# Скорость доступа к переменным

Tags: java, оптимизация, производительность

Есть ли разница в скорости доступа к локальным переменным по сравнению, скажем, с глобальными, или к переменным какого-то объекта, получаемыми через геттер?

К примеру, если мы организовываем цикл перебора элементов листа, будет ли быстрее получить локальную переменную `int size` и ставить в условие цикла её, чем дёргать `size()` метод листа?

То же самое с обычным массивом, есть ли разница, ссылаемся мы на локальную переменную в условии, или на `length` массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вот вы говорите «метод листа». Класса `List` нету, есть интерфейс с множеством реализаций. У большинства реализаций, конечно, метод `size()` очень простой: либо чтение поля, либо чтение длины массива, который хранится в поле. Но заранее не знаешь. У множества конкурентных коллекций (но не у списков) метод `size()` очень дорогой, обычно конкурентные коллекции размер не хранят. В любом случае обходить любую коллекцию надёжнее итератором, тогда `size()` и не потребуется.

Во-вторых, вы не упоминаете про то, какой виртуальной машиной вы пользуетесь. В хорошей виртуальной машине типа HotSpot Server VM, вы действительно можете во многих случаях полагаться на инлайнинг. За какой-нибудь Dalvik я не так уверен.

В-третьих, если вы, к примеру, используете интерфейс `List`, переданный параметром в метод, и вызываете этот метод с разными реализациями `List`, то профиль типа может быть отравлен и уже не получится эффективно сынлайнить.

Вот, скажем, как выглядит в x64-ассемблере, сгенерированном HotSpot, вызов `.size()` к методу, которому параметром передали `List`, но при этом до этого всегда по факту был `ArrayList`:

```
mov %rdx,%r10
mov 0x8(%rdx),%r8d  ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000000282987d
cmp $0xa70b6c0,%r8d  ;   {metadata('java/util/ArrayList')}
jne 0x0000000002829801  ;*invokeinterface size
                        ; - Test::sum@6 (line 17)
mov 0x10(%r10),%r9d  ;*getfield size
                     ; - java.util.ArrayList::size@1 (line 278)
                     ; - Test::sum@6 (line 17)
```

На входе в регистре `%rdx` указатель на наш список, он же копируется в `%r10`. Сперва мы читаем, что лежит по смещению `*(rdx+8)` (а там всегда лежит class-word: идентификатор класса объекта, который присваивается в рантайме при загрузке каждого класса) и сравниваем с некой волшебной константой `$0xa70b6c0` (когда JIT-компилятор компилировал этот метод, он, конечно, уже точно знал, какой идентификатор присвоен классу `ArrayList`). Эта проверка нужна, чтобы если в очередной раз метод вызвали с другим классом, можно было перейти на медленный путь и честно вызвать метод интерфейса. Заодно происходит неявная проверка аргумента на `null`: если в `rdx` оказался 0, здесь случится аппаратное исключение access violation, которое HotSpot перехватит и превратит в `NullPointerException`.

Если оказалось, что всё в порядке и у нас действительно `ArrayList`, то мы читаем напрямую поле size из объекта, обращаясь к `*(r10+0x10)`. Конечно, проверка, `ArrayList` у нас или нет, выполняется только один раз в методе. Если цикл полностью сынлайнился и JIT уверен, что `size` никто другой не меняет (другие потоки не в счёт: это ж не `volatile`), то поле больше не читается, а берётся из регистра. Поэтому в данном случае вы ничего не ускорите, сохранив результат в локальную переменную.

А вот если вы вызываете метод с разными реализациями списка, у вас будет честный интерфейсный вызов на каждой итерации.

Comment: там точно «отравлен»?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, по-английски говорят «polluted type profile». Можно и «загрязнён». Не думаю, что есть устоявшийся перевод.

Answer (score 7):

Не думайте о нанооптимизациях. Хороший оптимизирующий компилятор вынесет нужную переменную в регистр процессора сам, без вашей помощи. Причём он обычно лучше понимает, какую из них нужно выносить, а какую нет.

Но даже если это и не было бы так, всё равно вы должны писать как понятнее, не должны жертвовать поддерживаемостью кода ради выигрыша в один машинный такт.

И да, современные компиляторы умеют выносить не изменяемую в цикле величину за границы цикла. Уже давно.

Answer (score 3):

Язык Java создавался не для того, чтобы так сильно заострять внимание на производительности машинного уровня, но для того, чтобы быть больше сфокусированным на конкретной задаче. Поэтому всю эту работу на себя берет компилятор и виртуальная машина. Совсем другое дело, когда речь идет об производительности алгоритма для решаемой задачи, поэтому заострять внимание нужно именно на нем, ведь от его правильности будет зависеть намного больше.

Answer (score 1):

Кратко: всё зависит от того, что компилятору известно об используемых объектах, полях и методах.

Думать об оптимизации всегда полезно, главное не доводить до фанатизма.

Что касается Вашего примера, в общем случае всегда правильным будет результаты функций, а также выражения, которые будут использоваться несколько раз, копировать в локальные переменные. Например

```
for (int i = 0, listSize = list.size(); i  < listSize; i++) ...
```

Что же касается практики и конкретно java, тут всё зависит от того, что jit компилятор знает об используемых методах и классах. В наиболее частом случае, когда метод является геттером конкретного поля, известно что метод не переопределяется, или в конкретном месте известно, что будет использован конкретный класс, то компилятор сможет заменить такой вызов на прямое обращение к переменной, и если также известно что список в нашем примере не будет меняться в параллельных потоках, то могут быт последующие оптимизации, например,  копирование в локальную переменную, если поле не объявлено volatile.

Однако, если переменная в нашем случае list, может принимать ссылки на объекты различных классов List, и компилятор не может быть уверен что в конкретном месте будет обращение к конкретному классу, и что состояние объекта не будет изменено извне, то он, вероятно, скомпилирует выражение в обращение к методу интерфейса на каждой итерации цикла, что скажется на быстродействии.